# Visual Studio 2008 installer omits SDK 6.0A?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

As mentioned in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/006edcd4-888d-4b95-8454-9651dc298390), the Visual Studio 2008 installer sometimes silently fails to create the `Include` and `Lib` directories that are supposed to be created in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\`.

Does anybody know of a hotfix for the installer, or a reliable way to get the installation to succeed?  I am installing on a Win7/64 machine that already has VS2005 and VS2010 installed.  Uninstalling and reinstalling VS2008 itself does not work, nor does repairing the installation after it's created.  Can I avoid wiping the machine and starting over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On 64-bit systems, the SDK `Bin` folder ends up under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A`, but the `Include` and `Lib` folders end up under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A`.

This does not explain why the `Include` folder would be missing entirely, but it does explain some cases where maybe it would be overlooked on a 64-bit system.